# jquery contenteditable linebreak

Tags: php, jquery, html, contenteditable

I have a content editable area and I'm trying to disable enter/return and shift enter from creating a new paragraph, I have this working with the script below but it disables the buttons all together, what I wish to do is have return just place a line break rather then go to a new paragraph.

```
$("#content").keypress(function(e) {
    return e.which != 13;
});
```

All help appreciated!

Cheers,

Wazza

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
        $("#content").keypress(function(e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                e.preventDefault(); // I think this is the keyword you look for?
                $("#content").val($("#content").val() + "<br/>"); // Handler for new p or line break etc.
            }
        });
```

Comment: How can I control the cursor, not to go back to the beginning of the line after modifing the $("#content").text() or .html()? (the .val() does not work for me).

Answer (score 0):

See this answer on how to place the caret after the inserted node, plus on how to add a node : [Set caret position right after the inserted element in a contentEditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834793/set-caret-position-right-after-the-inserted-element-in-a-contenteditable-div/4836809#4836809)