# How do I get the element being edited?

Tags: javascript, html, focus, contenteditable, browser-extension

I'm developing a webapp, and I have a problem with the JavaScript.

The following is a simplified version of the HTML causing the problem. I have some nested `contenteditable` `divs` (I replaced the real content with placeholder text):

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="div1">
    text
    <div contenteditable="inherit" id="div2">
        text
        <div contenteditable="inherit" id="div3">
            text
        </div>
        text
    </div>
    text
</div>
```

*I want to get the element that's selected (being edited by the user) via JavaScript,* but so far I haven't found a way to do it (successfully).

---

**What I have tried and why it doesn't work:**

I have tried using `document.activeElement`, which is supposed to return whichever element is in focus. Normally this works, but it doesn't produce the desired result when working with nested `contenteditable` elements. Instead of returning the element that's being edited by the user, it returns the uppermost `contenteditable` ancestor.

For instance, if `div2` is selected/being edited, `document.activeElement` returns `div1`. If `div3` was selected/being edited, `document.activeElement` also returns `div1`.

*So I guess `document.activeElement` is not the right way to go about this.*

---

**How do I get the most specific element that's being edited, not its uppermost `contenteditable` ancestor?**

Comment: What do you exactly mean by getting focus?

Comment: For it to be the document.activeElement.

Comment: This question is not much of a "why isn't this code working" question. It's more of asking **how to do something,** after my first attempt failed.

Comment: The Really Best Way is making a `MutationObserver`. It's not very easy though

Comment: @Dimava Mutation observer wouldn't pick up pure interaction events though. Only mutations. You could provide an answer as an example, or if you want, I could. :)

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? It is incredibly difficult to get the focused element on nested `contenteditable`'s.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I did it by inserting a dummy element at the caret position and finding it's direct parent.

```
function getActiveDiv() {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    var node = document.createElement('span');
    range.insertNode(node);
    range = range.cloneRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(node);
    range.collapse(false);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    var activeDiv = node.parentNode;
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
    return activeDiv;
}
```

I did an example on fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/shhe05cj/4/

I run it on every keypress event that's bind to the relevant divs.

I based it on another thread that did something similar:[Set caret position right after the inserted element in a contentEditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834793/set-caret-position-right-after-the-inserted-element-in-a-contenteditable-div)

Comment: Works perfectly for me!

Answer (score 3):

Seems to work fine for me in this fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/dgrundel/huL4sjem/

I'm using this code to check:

```
<div contenteditable="true" class="edit">
    This is editable.
</div>

<script>
    $('.edit').on('click', function(){
        console.log(document.activeElement);
    });
</script>
```

When I click into the editable element, console gets a copy of the div logged to it.

Comment: Does it have to be like that for it to work? My div is contenteditable inherit, and my parent div is contenteditable.

Comment: Yes. You are editing the entire `contenteditable` parent element, not just the child, so it will be what gets the focus.

Comment: Then the answer does not solve my problem. How do I get the most specific element in focus/being edited?

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('#edit').on('click', function() {
  // this is the innermost *node*
  var an = window.getSelection().anchorNode;
  // this is the innermost *element*
  var ae = an;
  while (!( ae instanceof Element ))
    ae = ae.parentElement;
  $('#an').text(an.nodeValue);
  $('#ae').text(ae.outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" id="edit">
  This is editable. <span>What?</span> <em>How about this?</em>
</div>
<br/>
Active Node:<br/>
<pre id="an">Nothing</pre>
<br/>
Active Element:<br/>
<pre id="ae">Nothing</pre>
<br/>
```

Here you go. Hit "Run snippet." Have fun.

The example below shows the behavior using the `input` event. This would mimic the behavior of a mutation observer.

```js
$('#edit').on('input', function() {
  // this is the innermost *node*
  var an = window.getSelection().anchorNode;
  // this is the innermost *element*
  var ae = an;
  while (!( ae instanceof Element ))
    ae = ae.parentElement;
  $('#an').text(an.nodeValue);
  $('#ae').text(ae.outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" id="edit">
  This is editable. <span>What?</span> <em>How about this?</em>
</div>
<br/>
Active Node:<br/>
<pre id="an">Nothing</pre>
<br/>
Active Element:<br/>
<pre id="ae">Nothing</pre>
<br/>
```

The example below shows the behavior using the `keydown` and `keyup` events. This would catch non-modifying keypresses like arrows and modifier keys.

```js
$('#edit').on('keydown keyup', function() {
  // this is the innermost *node*
  var an = window.getSelection().anchorNode;
  // this is the innermost *element*
  var ae = an;
  while (!( ae instanceof Element ))
    ae = ae.parentElement;
  $('#an').text(an.nodeValue);
  $('#ae').text(ae.outerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" id="edit">
  This is editable. <span>What?</span> <em>How about this?</em>
</div>
<br/>
Active Node:<br/>
<pre id="an">Nothing</pre>
<br/>
Active Element:<br/>
<pre id="ae">Nothing</pre>
<br/>
```

Comment: @Dimava Added examples to show the difference between the `input` and `keydown` and `keyup` ... I skipped `keypress` because that would be redundant, but you get the idea. :)

Comment: @narawagames You marked this as an answer, then unmarked it? Why?

Answer (score 0):

This does the job for me:

```
   $(document).click(function(event) {
            console.log(event.target);
        });
```

Comment: Nope, he wanted the element that being edited, not the one that was clicked.