# How to get the div where the cursor is present in a contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I am looking into writing a simple code editor for JavaScript. Currently a `div` with `contenteditable` seems the more appropriate than a text area. But still it feels very rudimentary in terms of getting cursor div.

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <div><br></div>
    <div>123</div>
    <div><br></div>
    <div>abc</div>
</div>
```

This is a `div` where I have four lines and I have placed the cursor on line two (`<div>123</div>`). Is there a way to get the div where the cursor is present, efficiently? My current method is

```
var xpath = "//div[text()='123']";
var matchingElement = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
```

I want to insert a new `div` after the obtained `div`, which I do as follows:

```
var d = document.createElement("div")
var b = document.createElement("br")
d.appendChild(b)
matchingElement.parentNode.insertBefore(d, matchingElement.nextSibling);
```

Here the problem is if the text in the `div` is large, wouldn't it lead to performance issues while doing a string comparison on every dom element?

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31093285/how-do-i-get-the-element-being-edited It may not address finding _nested_ contentEditable elements when the cursor is sitting passively, but if events are being triggered (such as `keyup`), or if the element has no contentEditable anscestors, options exist here.

Comment: Actually, even if neither of the above conditions is met, you could fire a custom event that triggers the solution from the accepted answer to that question.