# Trigger ENTER event in contentEditable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a contenteditable div and would like to trigger an 'enter' when certain keys (like D) are pressed. Below code doesn't work...

```js
$('#div_edit').keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 68) {
        var k = jQuery.Event('keypress', { which: 13 });
        $('#div_edit').trigger(k);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_edit" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

I'm only concerned about Chrome.

EDIT: I would like to add that everytime the D key is pushed, it creates a new element 'div' inside the contenteditable where the user can continue typing in the new div/new line. Example:

```
<div id="div_edit" contenteditable="true">
    <div>The start of the sentence</div>
    <div>user hit D so continue typing here</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT: I guess my main question is, is there no way to trigger an ENTER in a contenteditable element???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this brings you closer to what you are trying to do:

```js
// function from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834793/set-caret-position-right-after-the-inserted-element-in-a-contenteditable-div/4836809#4836809
function insertNodeAtCaret(node) {
  if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount) {
      var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
      range.collapse(false);
      range.insertNode(node);
      range = range.cloneRange();
      range.selectNodeContents(node);
      range.collapse(false);
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(range);
    }
  } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    var html = (node.nodeType == 1) ? node.outerHTML : node.data;
    var id = "marker_" + ("" + Math.random()).slice(2);
    html += '<span id="' + id + '"></span>';
    var textRange = document.selection.createRange();
    textRange.collapse(false);
    textRange.pasteHTML(html);
    var markerSpan = document.getElementById(id);
    textRange.moveToElementText(markerSpan);
    textRange.select();
    markerSpan.parentNode.removeChild(markerSpan);
  }
}
$('#div_edit').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 68) {
    insertNodeAtCaret(document.createElement("br"));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_edit" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: your code creates a new element like it should, but on every keypress of D it creates yet another element inside of the first element. <div><div></div></div> (changed to 'div' from br). How would I get it to just create a <div></div> after text typed in div_edit and move carat there to continue? Hence:
`<div id="div_edit">previous text<div>continue here</div></div>`

Answer (score 0):

What about :

(Range part is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125292/how-to-move-cursor-to-end-of-contenteditable-entity)- Nico Burns's answer)

```
  $('#div_edit').keydown(function(e) {
      if(e.keyCode == 68) {
        var br = document.createElement("br");
        var div_edit = document.getElementById("div_edit");
        div_edit.appendChild(br);

        var range = document.createRange();//Create a range (a range is a like the selection but invisible)
        range.selectNodeContents(div_edit);//Select the entire contents of the element with the range
        range.collapse(false);//collapse the range to the end point. false means collapse to end rather than the start
        var selection = window.getSelection();//get the selection object (allows you to change selection)
        selection.removeAllRanges();//remove any selections already made
        selection.addRange(range);//make the range you have just created the visible selection
     }
});
```

Comment: this code works somewhat, especially if I specified to append a div or p, but my main problem is trying to get the carat/cursor inside the newly created element.

Comment: I have updated the answer , try that. I think it will help.