# ContentEditable div - set cursor position after updating inner html

Tags: javascript, html, dom, contenteditable, cursor-position

I have a spell check solution that uses a content editable `div` and inserts `span` tags around words that are misspelled. Every time the inner html of the `div` is updated, the cursor moves to the beginning of the `div`.

I know I can move the cursor to the end of the `div` if the user adds new words to the end of the sentence (code below).

> Old Text: This is a spell checker|
>
> New Text: This is a spell checker soluuution|

```
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(element[0]);
range.collapse(false);
var sel = window.getSelection();
sel.removeAllRanges();
sel.addRange(range);
```

However, I am unable to retain the cursor position if the user adds words in the middle of a sentence.

> Old Text: This is a spell checker
>
> New Text: This is a new spell checker|

In the above case, the cursor goes to the end of the `div` when it should be after "new".

How do I retain the cursor position? Since I am updating the html and adding nodes, saving the range before the update and adding it to the selection object isn't working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check if [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834793/set-caret-position-right-after-the-inserted-element-in-a-contenteditable-div) answers your question. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, @Pyromonk - unfortunately, that approach doesn't work for me as I need to update the innerHtml of the div and hence, any marker nodes are lost.

Comment: That's a shame. I will try to be on the lookout for something that might help. Using a separate element just for input while updating the div's innerHTML is out of the question, I presume?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. I have tried to update the inner html while still keeping  the marker node and then select it but I keep getting a "The given range isn't in document" error.

Comment: What about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767848/get-caret-cursor-position-in-contenteditable-area-containing-html-content

Comment: @HAL9256 can you share any code snippet or fiddle link for more clarification? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, changing the content of the div will always have problem.

So here is the solution that I came with. Please type error word such as helloo, dudeee

This should ideally work for textarea as well.

Solution details:

- Use a ghost div with same text content
- Use transparent color for the ghost div
- Use border-bottom for the ghost div span text
- Change zIndex so that it does't appear infront

```js
// some mock logic to identify spelling error
const errorWords = ["helloo", "dudeee"];

// Find words from string like '   Helloo   world .. '
// Perhaps you could find a better library you that does this logic.
const getWords = (data) =>{
  console.log("Input: ", data);
  const allWords = data.split(/\b/);
  console.log("Output: ", allWords)
  return allWords;
}

// Simple mock logic to identify errors. Now works only for 
// two words [ 'helloo', 'dudeee']
const containsSpellingError = word => {
  const found = errorWords.indexOf(word) !== -1;
  console.log("spell check:", word, found);
  return found;
}

const processSpellCheck = text => {
  const allWords = getWords(text);
  console.log("Words in the string: ", allWords);
  const newContent = allWords.map((word, index) => {
    var text = word;
    if(containsSpellingError(word.toLowerCase())) {
      console.log("Error word found", word);
      text = $("<span />")
        .addClass("spell-error")
        .text(word);
    }
    return text;
  });
  return newContent;
}

function initalizeSpellcheck(editorRef) {
  var editorSize = editorRef.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  var spellcheckContainer = $("<div />", {})
    .addClass("spell-check")
    .prop("spellcheck", "false");
 
  var spellcheckSpan = $("<span />")
    .addClass("spell-check-text-content")
    .css({
      width: editorSize.width,
      height: editorSize.height,
      position: "absolute",
      zIndex: -1
    });
    
  var text = $(editorRef).text();
  
  var newContent = processSpellCheck(text);
  spellcheckSpan.append(newContent);
  
  spellcheckContainer.append(spellcheckSpan);
  spellcheckContainer.insertBefore(editorRef);
  
  $(editorRef).on("input.spellcheck", function(event) {
      var newText = $(event.target).text();
      var newContent = processSpellCheck(newText); 
      $(".spell-check .spell-check-text-content").text("");
      $(".spell-check .spell-check-text-content").append(newContent);
  });
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  var editor = document.querySelector("#editor");
  initalizeSpellcheck(editor);
});
```

```css
#editor {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
}

.spell-check {
  color: transparent;
}

.spell-error {
  border-bottom: 3px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
dudeee
</div>
```

Comment: Finding words is based on space character.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might work from SitePoint:

Store the selection x, y:

```js
cursorPos=document.selection.createRange().duplicate();
clickx = cursorPos.getBoundingClientRect().left;
clicky = cursorPos.getBoundingClientRect().top;
```

Restore the selection:

```js
cursorPos = document.body.createTextRange();
cursorPos.moveToPoint(clickx, clicky);
cursorPos.select();
```

SitePoint Article: [Saving/restoring caret position in a contentEditable div](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/saving-restoring-caret-position-in-a-contenteditable-div/1911/2)

**Update 25.10.2019:**

The solution mentioned above doesn't work anymore since functions are used that are deprecated. [Does chrome supports document.selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003784/does-chrome-supports-document-selection)