# contenteditable div get cursor position

Tags: javascript, html

I found a code snippet that works fine except when there is a line break. Hitting enter creates html element and the function produces wrong result. Anyone with solution to this ?

I used the following script so far:
http://niichavo.wordpress.com/2009/01/06/contenteditable-div-cursor-position/

Answer (score 2):

The issue your facing is due to browser differences. For example, I.E will add `<p></p>` tags when you hit enter and then `<br/>` when hitting shift-Enter. Chrome implements `<div>...</div>` around the content when you hit enter and `<br/>` when hitting shift-Enter.

You need to handle this by capturing keypress events or using a jQuery plugin that will make the enter keypress standard across browsers.  There are Stack Overflow questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057881/avoid-ie-contenteditable-element-to-create-paragraphs-on-enter-key) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066890/jquery-contenteditable-linebreak) that would help.

Here is the code I used to test this out.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#ShowButton').click(function (e) {
            alert($('#CED').html());
        });
    });    
</script>

<canvas id="drawingSurface" class="canvasLayout">

</canvas>

<div id="CED" contenteditable="true">
    Text goes here
</div>

<input type="button" value="Show HTML" id="ShowButton" />
```